# XML Serialization and Deserialization without an XmlRoot element

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class A which has a list of B objects as marked using the Xml attributes

```
[Serializable]
A
{
       int A1{get;set}

       [XmlArray("Bs")]
       [XmlArrayItem("B")]
       List<B> Bs;
}


[Serializable]
B
{
       [XmlAttribute("b1")]
       int B1{get; set}

       [XmlAttribute("b2")]
       string B2{get; set}
}
```

I want my XML to look like this:

```
<Bs>
    <B b1=1 b2="somevalue1" />
    <B b1=2 b2="somevalue2" />
    <B b1=3 b2="somevalue3" />
    <B b1=4 b2="somevalue4" />
</Bs>
```

I just want to serialize the attribute Bs. I dont want to serialize A. I am currently getting an error:

```
There is an error in XML document (1,2) , System.InvalidOperationException: <Bs xlms:“”> was not expected
```

What can I do to serialize just B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is chopped up from a real example, but there are a few issues here.

Your classes and properties need to be public, and your class needs to include the `class` keyword:

```
public class B
{
    [XmlAttribute("b1")]
    public int B1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("b2")]
    public string B2 { get; set; }
}
```

As an aside, the `Serializable` attribute isn't necessary as it's unrelated to `XmlSerializer`.

To serialise a `List<B>` with a specific root name, you need to create an `XmlSerializer` as below:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<B>), new XmlRootAttribute("Bs"));
```

Your XML is also invalid, as each of your b1 attributes required quotes.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LKwPkn) for a working example.

Comment: As you mentioned, this example is a watered down version of the real thing, and all was solved using "var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<B>), new XmlRootAttribute("Bs"));"